# Missing Upvotes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, votes

I went through several of [KCotreau](https://superuser.com/users/83981/kcotreau?tab=reputation)'s answers yesterday upvoting, showing my appreciation using the upvotes I had left near the end of the day.

This morning, I found none of my votes for him from yesterday have apparently been recorded.

Please check this out and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You triggered the filter that prevents too many upvotes from user X to user Y in a certain time period.

[@DanielBeck and I had this problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2865056#2865056) before, but it seems his votes got through after all – there was a misunderstanding involving reputation recalc.

The details of this filter aren't known, and obviously won't be undisclosed, however the general rule is: If you spend *x* votes on user *X*, you should probably spend the same amount on other users too.

Apart from that, there's nothing to be done about it.

Comment: KCotreau got [6 upvotes 20 minutes ago](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Scjw.png), by the way. Just for the record :)

Comment: So when do we roll out the apology committee to him?

Comment: And the upvotes apparently triggered [8 badges](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Or7aO.png) too...

Comment: @sblair That's great. Lost the votes, got to keep the badges...